# How to ignore stop words and use remaining words to fetch expected results alone using Solr?

Tags: search, solr, stop-words

I have a `name` field, with the following definition:

```
    <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

and I would like to search for contents based on the following criteria:

Example values:

```
test a value
test of solr
not a value
test me says value
```

So, if i do search for `test value`, I should only get results containing both `test` and `values`. And, even if I do `test a value`, I should still get only the same result as stop words will be excluded. But, with this current setup, even with including `edismax` in the solr query, I get all of the results. It goes by a record with either of those two tokens. Could someone suggest me the update I could do to the definition to get a result as expected? And, am I using stopwords as expected? I do not want stopwords in the search consuming execution time.

I updated the definition as per the suggestion and even then the result does not make any sense to me.

I have a value `what a term`. And, there are other values like `what the term` ; `about a term`; `about the term`; `description test`; `Name a Nothing` etc. A search for `what a term` returns all of these. And, I also had a value just `a` and `the`. They were also getting returned in the result. Though, for `what a term`, as per the below screenshot, the query omits the stop word, the result does not make any sense to me.

[image]

Comment: You can use index and query as separate analyzer. From query analyzer remove the stopward filter factory.

Comment: Please refer the below field type.<fieldType name="nametext" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory" words="keepwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syns.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: I have posted the updated definition in the comment itself. I still see the same behavior @AbhijitBashetti

Comment: why are you using KeywordTokenizerFactory...?KeywordTokenizerFactory does not create the tokens of your text...it keeps the text as single token...in this case others filters of no use...

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the stopsword during the search and index time. You cannot ignore these words in the response. The response will come as the text is stores as it is. The data stored for search and response is different. Search happens on the indexed data. In the response you get the data stored.

In your field type definition you are using `KeywordTokenizerFactory`.

`KeywordTokenizerFactory` : is used to when you dont want to create any tokens of your text. This tokenizer treats the entire text field as a single token.

Use of any other filter is of no use after this.

You can use `StandardTokenizerFactory` instead `KeywordTokenizerFactory`.
`StandardTokenizerFactory` : This tokenizer splits the text field into tokens, treating whitespace and punctuation as delimiters.

```
<fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

On the analysis page, I analyzed the data for the above field.
Index the data "test a value" and query it with "test value", the result is found. Here you can see while indexing the data the stopwords are skipped as we have applied the `stopwordfilterfactory`

[image: sc1]

Now use "test a value" while indexing as well query in the analyze page.
It skips the stopword "a" as filter is applied and matched the result.

[image: sc2]

Comment: Though in analysis I see something similar the search result does not make any sense. Any thoughts?

Comment: I did not get you...what is wrong with the analysis?

Comment: I have a value what a term. And, there are other values like what the term ; about a term; about the term; description test; Name a Nothing etc. A search for what a term returns all of these. And, I also had a value just a and the. They were also getting returned in the result. Though, for what a term, as per the below screenshot, the query omits the stop word, the result does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Search will not happen on the search term like a, the,of...these are stop words...and not indexed to solr...in the response you will get these words as the text are stored as it is...because in the schema we ask so..